# Как сверстать с помощью flex-box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Есть такая разметка, можно ли без дополнительных оберток сделать это на флексбокс?
Что должно получится прикрепляю изображением.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<ul class="cakes__list">
        <li class="cakes__item cakes__item--classic">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="cakes__item-name">Классические</span>
            <span class="cakes__item-count">
              <span>24</span>
              Вида
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="cakes__item cakes__item--mousses">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="cakes__item-name">Муссовые</span>
            <span class="cakes__item-count">
              <span>12</span>
              Видов
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="cakes__item cakes__item--wedding">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="cakes__item-name">Свадебные</span>
            <span class="cakes__item-count">
              <span>20</span>
              Видов
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="cakes__item cakes__item--men">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="cakes__item-name">Мужчинам</span>
            <span class="cakes__item-count">
              <span>12</span>
              Видов
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="cakes__item cakes__item--women">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="cakes__item-name">Женщинам</span>
            <span class="cakes__item-count">
              <span>16</span>
              Видов
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="cakes__item cakes__item--children">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="cakes__item-name">Детские</span>
            <span class="cakes__item-count">
              <span>18</span>
              Видов
            </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

Comment: Нет, нельзя. А вот на float'ах - легко.

Comment: А на гридах?...

Comment: На гридах можно. Хотя с IE будут проблемы - надо каждому блоку место в сетке говорить.

Comment: Спасибо, как раз давно хотел изучить гриды.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, на flexbox нельзя. А вот на float'ах - легко.

```css
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 40%;
  padding: .5em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 3em;
  float: left;
}

a {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: silver;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  width: 60%;
  height: 6em;
}

li:nth-child(6n+2), li:nth-child(6n+3), li:nth-child(6n+4) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>1</a></li>
  <li><a>2</a></li>
  <li><a>3</a></li>
  <li><a>4</a></li>
  <li><a>5</a></li>
  <li><a>6</a></li>
  <li><a>7</a></li>
  <li><a>8</a></li>
  <li><a>9</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, временно сделаю на флоатах!
Буду изучать гриды.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦  Буду благодарен и поставлю плюсик если добавите решение на гридах;)

Comment: @midia, попозже попробую написать. Сейчас пока некогда.